# Javascript: Object Expected Error on Auto Complete

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an Object Expected error on my production server, but not my preview server.  The only difference (to my knowledge) is that my preview server uses an older version of IIS.  But I don't know why it would cause this error?

The error is on this line in my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" name="txtprjName" tabindex="1" size="100" maxlength="50" />
<span id="txtHint"></span>
```

showHint is refering to an external javascript file in the same directory as the HTML file.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="clienthint.js"></script>
```

And the content of clienthint.js is this:

```
var xmlHttp
function showHint(str){
    if (str.length==0){ 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    if (xmlHttp==null){
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    } 
    var url="gethint.asp";
    url=url+"?q="+str;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
} 
function stateChanged() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    var xmlHttp=null    
    try{
        // Internet Explorer
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e){
        try{
            // Internet Explorer
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working?  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: please debug it. if you have a specific question, please ask.

Comment: BTW: Add the missing semicolons; and in browsers that don't support Ajax it should fail silently instead of alerting on every keystroke - the hint is not substantial to your application.

Comment: The error I have listed at the top - the first line of HTML. onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"  

Not sure I follow the missing semicolons question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the javascript to the main web page instead of having it included externally, and the code works now.